# Preloader infinito

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-animations

Apliquei um preloader em um site mas ele "não desliga" por assim dizer.

```js
$(window).on('load', function () {
    $('#preloader .inner').fadeOut();
    $('#preloader').delay(350).fadeOut('slow'); 
    $('body').delay(350).css({'overflow': 'visible'});
});
```

```html
<div id="preloader">
    <div class="inner">
       <div class="bolas">
          <div></div>
          <div></div>
          <div></div>                    
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Um erro que aparece é:

> preloader.js:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
>       at preloader.js:2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você está usando um código que precisa da biblioteca Jquery e não adicionou ela.

Adicione ela antes deste script que precise dela; você pode usar uma fonte CDN

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado! Resolveu o problema.